# Result with multiple counts on other queries

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do here is possible or the best approach, but I would like to avoid multiple queries to achieve a simple result set.

My application allows for a number of admins and users on their account. I want to return a single result set which based on their account type could return the amount of admins and users (which is fixed values in a table) but also return the amount of admins/users already assigned.

To best explain here is an example (which I know does not work but should give an indication of what I'm trying to do:

```
 SELECT 
      `admins`,
      `users`,
      COUNT(SELECT id FROM `account_admins` WHERE `account_id`=?) AS `current_admins`, 
      COUNT(SELECT id FROM `account_users` WHERE `acount_id`=?) AS `current_users`
 FROM ....
```

I'm not sure if the above is possible and if it's efficient? I have been advised that I could use joins but I'm not entirely sure how to go about it esspecially with multiple COUNT() requests.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subquery approach is almot correct.  You want to put the `count()` inside the subquery:

```
 SELECT 
      `admins`,
      `users`,
      (SELECT count(id) FROM `account_admins` WHERE `account_id`=?) AS `current_admins`, 
      (SELECT count(id) FROM `account_users` WHERE `acount_id`=?) AS `current_users`
 FROM ....
```